# Add scientific names to text in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word, text-editing

I regularly need to add scientific names after bird makes in reports. There are three bird names sprinkled around the text below: Tennessee Warbler (Leiothlypis peregrina), Green Warbler (Phylloscopus trochiloides) and Red-breasted Nuthatch (Sitta canadensis).

The first instance of each bird name in the text below should have its scientific name added, subsequent instances of the name don’t need scientific added. I wondering what is the most efficient way of doing this?

Lorem ipsum Green Warbler dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et Dolore Tennessee Warbler magna aliqua. Ut enim Red-breasted Nuthatch ad minim veniam, quis Nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute Irure Dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui Officia deserunt mollit anim id est Tennessee Warbler laborum extra. Lorem Red-breasted Nuthatch Green Warbler ipsum dolor sit Green Warbler amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation Ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Tennessee Warbler Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non Proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum extra Red-breasted Nuthatch.

Comment: Search and replace? What have you tried?

Comment: Just do Search and Replace from the beginning of the document and only replace the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup each bird name up as an AutoCorrect entry so that every time you type, for example, Tennessee Warbler ... it autocorrects to `Tennessee Warbler (Leiothlypis peregrina)`.

The Autocorrect function of Word is located on the Proofing group in Word Options (or Preferences if you are running a Mac version of Word). Checkout Word's Help for additional information on Autocorrect.

If there are times that you want to enter the bird name without the scientific name being appended, then you only have to press Undo after the scientific name is inserted by the Autocorrect function.

Comment: That's good suggestion. However, the key thing is that only the first instance of each bird name needs a scientific name after it. In long and complex documents, its too time consuming to keep checking whether a bird name is the first instance of that name. So I tend to add scientific names after text is written.

Comment: @luciano if that is a requirement, your should add it to your question. The AutoCorrect feature would still be a valid solution. For example, set a shortcut of =TW that inserts just the scientific name of a Tennessee Warbler and then you have complete control of when you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is simply to do a Find and Replace from the beginning of the document, and only replace the first instance.